# Access to the path "somepath" is denied."

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream

When i execute this code in my C# console application, it throws `"Access to the path "somepath" is denied"` on `using` line.

This is my code.

```
static public PdfDocument Open(string PdfPath)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(PdfPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        int len = (int)fileStream.Length;
        Byte[] fileArray = new Byte[len];
        fileStream.Read(fileArray, 0, len);
        return Open(fileArray);
    }
}
```

What is going wrong. Any thought? By the way I logged in as system admin and I have full control in the given folder.

Comment: Does `PdfPath` actually contain file name? Side note: consider [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of writing your own.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: Yes PdfPath contains .pdf file.

Comment: Your comment here does not match comment on Dan's answer. If you want reasonable answers you need to provide code that show problem. So far you shown manual implementation of `File.ReadAllBytes` but did not show exact error message and input value that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file is open by another process in exclusive write mode.

Comment: in my code i am not reading the file exclusively I am reading the folder so it will read the contents of the folder as well.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov - string path = @"D:\temp";

Comment: You have to open a specific file with FileStream. You can't open a folder. You need to pass an actual full file name, not just a folder path.

Comment: @Baldrick - using the same code while displaying outpout in console screen its working fine but while trying to write output in local disk drive its throwing the exception.Hope u understood my points.

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's not quite clear what you mean. You say 'trying to write output', but your code above is trying to read, not write.